# Change openid on all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, openid

getopenid is closing its doors, so I need to make sure I'm not locked out. 
I have added my Google OpenId on stackoverflow.com, and did the "swap".

Now, is there any shortcut for doing the same on all other Stack Exchange sites of which I am a member?  How do I even know which Stack Exchange sites I belong too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know what sites you are a member of by looking at the [accounts tab of your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134271/nealwalters?tab=accounts).

You can copy your data out to all of these sites at once.  At the bottom of your accounts tab, there are 3 buttons relating to your network accounts:

[image: network association buttons]

The bottom one is the one you want in this situation.  Choosing the first one does not include copying your OpenID information.

Comment: Cool, I never noticed the "Accounts" tab before.

Answer (score 3):

Head over to your [profiles page, accounts tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160245/nealwalters?tab=accounts) and click on "Copy Stack Overflow login credentials to all Stack Exchange sites"

[image]